# Eclipse CDT Debug console not displaying program output

Tags: eclipse-cdt, eclipse-3.4

I am using [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Eclipse Ganymede Package - version 3.4.2)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/ganymedesr2) on Windows XP with [MinGW GCC 4.2.1](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435&package_id=241304&release_id=532062) and [GDB 6.8-3](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=2435&filename=gdb-6.8-mingw-3.tar.bz2&a=53789889).

I am facing a problem very similar to that mentioned [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg12971.html).  A simple hello world program will not print to the console output in the debugger. A run command displays the output correctly. I have checked both gdb output console and the output console.

What are the right settings to get the output in console window of eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

//have you put endl at the end of your output?

```
int main()
{
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"; // prints nothing to console ; no endl
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!! twice
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding the endl flush worked for me but there is a lot of discussion around this and I am not sure if this always works. It is worth looking at the related windows issues (which seems to be tied to a 32 vs 64 bit environment problem): http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=197552&start=0&S=2a2b64e1f1404705c0214976bd477428