# OS X 10.6.4 + Eclipse 3.5 + latest CDT not outputting cout/printf to console

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

I spend most of my time in Eclipse these days, so I thought I would check out what Eclipse's C++ support was like (I usually use Xcode on Mac and Visual Studio for Windows).

I found the CDT package for Eclipse 3.5, so I installed it.

Everything installed properly and the default C++ "Hello World" project compiled nicely, however for the life of me I can't get any application output piped to the console.  I've tried everything, and searched around for solutions, but it seems I'm not the only one.  Most have trouble in Windows, but I haven't seen a lot of issues with OS X.

Of course, if I run the compiled output in a bash shell, it displays output properly.

This is how simple the default app is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Shane

Comment: Works for me in OSX 10.6.4, eclipse Build id: 20100617-1415 Helios. I had a console view open from the build

Comment: And you can see output from your app in the console? i.e. cout works?

Comment: Does not work for me in OSX 10.5.8 and eclipse Build id: 20100218-1602 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2.M20100211-1343 org.eclipse.platform.ide)

Comment: Update - I was able to get it working by adding '<< endl' but Shane appears to already have that above. Note that there is a known bug in this area for windows so it may be related - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888241/eclipse-cdt-debug-console-not-displaying-program-output/1450550#1450550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this in Helios 3.6 and it works. Must be a 3.5 problem.